# Android. How to execute function in main thread after delay?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-handler

I need to make some function in UI thread but after delay. I need the delay to not block the main thread. Fox example I have function `makeSmthInMainThread()` which I want to call in main thread after delay.

Here is my code:

```
GlobalScope.launch {
        delay(3000)
        makeSmthInMainThread()
    }
```

Can you please tell me in this case the function will be executed in the main thread? Or do I need to wrap it in `withContext(Dispatchers.Main)` ?

Perhaps in this case it is better to use `Handler()` and `postDelayed` ?

Please, help me.

Answer (score 4):

GlobalScope by default uses a background thread from Dispatchers.Default, so it will fail unless you use `.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {` or wrap the main thread code in `withContext(Dispatchers.Main) { }`.

But GlobalScope is not suitable for a coroutine that does anything to any members of your Activity (properties or functions of your Activity), because GlobalScope coroutines do not automatically get cancelled when your Activity goes off screen. Your coroutine will leak the activity.

Use `lifecycleScope.launch` so it will automatically cancel the coroutine if your Activity is destroyed, and it uses the main thread by default:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    delay(1000)
    doSomethingThatMustBeDoneOnMainThread()
}
```

If you did use Handler and `postDelayed`, you would still have the problem with leaking the Activity. The appropriate solution there would be to keep a reference to your Handler in a property and clear all its messages in `onDestroy()`. Likewise, with GlobalScope, you could keep your launched coroutine in a `Job?` property and cancel it in `onDestroy()` to avoid leaking the activity.

Since `lifecycleScope` does this automatically, it's the simpler technique.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `launch(Dispatchers.Main)` or `withContext(Dispatchers.Main)` to execute the function in the **Main Thread**. By default `GlobalScope.launch` runs in a **Worker Thread**. But be careful, `GlobalScope` is a delicate API, please read the docs before using it, it can create resource and memory leaks. Consider using [`viewModelScope`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#viewmodelscope) property in `ViewModel` class or [`lifecycleScope`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#lifecyclescope) property in `Activity`/`Fragment` to launch coroutines.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to specify the Dispatcher, GlobalScope is not MainThread.

```
GlobalScope.launch {
    delay(3000)
    withContext(Dispatchers.Main.immediate) {
        makeSmthInMainThread()
    }
}
```

Comment: This will likely leak the activity. The immediate dispatcher is dispensable here because the coroutine is definitely not on the main thread when it reaches the `withContext` block.